# Python3 - How to know if a letter that is not in a variable is in a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I know that the question is confusing. Let me explain.

I am coding a Scrabble Trainer in Python3. You get a set of 7 letters(which can repeat) and you have to make as many words as possible just from those letters. I want the user to get an error if they use a letter which is not in that set. How can I do this?

```
a = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
b = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
c = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
d = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
e = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
f = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
g = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
print ("Your letters are...")
print (a)
print (b)
print (c)
print (d)
print (e)
print (f)
print (g)
```

Where to go from here?!

Comment: Don't post the link, Post your code here.

Comment: Is that okay? I am sorry I am new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools` module to find all permutations of letters. Get user input and check if it's not in any of the permutations.

```
import itertools 
user_in = input()
if user_in not in [''.join(word) for word in itertools.permutations([a, b, c, d, e, f, g])]:
    print('Something is not in the letter')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your letters in a list, and then do:

`set(word) in set(letters)`

Comment: Ok, but how do I check if a character in the word that the user inputs is not in the set. So how do I make an if else statement with that considering that the user input is a variable.

Comment: If the condition mentioned above is `True`, then **all** characters in the input word is in the set of your letters. If it is `False`, then there is at least one character in the input word which is not present in your letter set.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you would just run a for loop like this:

```
Same=False
for letterX in Variable:
    for lettersY in String:
        if letterX==lettersY:
            print("Letter in string and variable")
            Same=True
    if Same==False:
        print("Letter not in string")
    else:
        print("")
```